# How is "sendmail: MTA: accepting connections" a correct commandline?

Tags: command-line, proc

`cat /proc/21637/cmdline` says `sendmail: MTA: accepting connections` which I cannot imagine to be a correct command line. Since I don't have `sendmail` installed nor do I find it in `PATH` and not even something that seems convenient in the output of `locate sendmail` it makes me worried (I'll ask a separate question if you tell me that the cmdline indicates an issue).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 with Linux 4.8.0-32-generic.

Comment: Related on [unix.se]: [How does curl protect a password from appearing in ps output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385339/how-does-curl-protect-a-password-from-appearing-in-ps-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applications can (and do) rewrite their command line arguments *after* they have started. Sometimes this is done for security purposes, sometimes for ease of presentation. IIRC, `mysql` or some other DB command would remove passwords given as arguments from the argument list.

I'm not sure of the method usually used for this, but one way is to re-exec with new arguments:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *args[], char *env[])
{
    char *argv[] = {"bar: accepting", "blah", NULL};
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        int fd = open("/proc/self/exe", O_RDONLY);
        fexecve(fd, argv, env);
    }
    else
        sleep(100);
}
```

Testing:

```
$ make foo
cc     foo.c   -o foo
$ ./foo & pgrep -fa bar
[1] 18047
18047 bar: accepting blah
```

Note the PIDs.

To see the actual executable being used, check `/proc/<PID>/exe`:

```
$ ./foo & ls -l /proc/$!/exe
[1] 18025
3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 0 Jan  7 00:59 /proc/18025/exe -> /home/muru/foo
```